# Printing asterisks using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

A method, `printStars(j)`, is available that returns a string -- a row of `j` asterisks. I need to write a method that recursively prints a triangle of `n` rows of asterisks. The first row needs to have one *, the second have two *s, etc. No iterative loops can be used (so no while, do-while, or for).

The code to do it backwards is simple enough:

```
public void printTriangle(int n) {
    if(n >= 1) {
        printStars(n));
        printTriangle(n - 1);
    }
}
```

My code thus far for the above but reversed is below. It is incorrect as `i` is reset to 1 in each loop. I'm just not sure how to go about it. I can only use a one-parameter function.

```
public void printTriangle(int n) {
    int i = 1;

    if(i <= n) {
        printStars(i);
        printTriangle(i + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: usually, (quite often in, for example, prolog) you create two functions. one as 'public interface' and one that does the work: pT_aux(int n, int i) { ... } pT(int n) { pT_aux(n, 1); } hth

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just first recur, then print the line:

```
public void printTriangle(int n) {
    if(n > 1) {
        printTriangle(n - 1);
    }
    System.out.println(makeStars(n));
}
```

So the smaller triangle is printed first, and then the longer line appended.

Comment: This is printing the triangle correctly, but it puts an extra line break both before and after the triangle, which is considered incorrect. Is that something that can be controlled for, or is that being handled by `makeStars` (which I can't see or edit)? Actually, the method for the second part is called printStars, and it actually prints the entire line. That's why I ask this question. I'm editing my post now.

Comment: I took that condition from your example, where you also print an extra blank line. Changing the condition for recurring to `if (i > 1)` leaves the leading blank line out.

Comment: @HotLicks To recurse would mean something different, "to curse again", wouldn't it?

Comment: @DanielFischer -- Definitely!

Answer (score 1):

```
static int i = 1;
```

This will ensure that `i` retains its value between calls to the function.
It is initialized to 1 the first time, and any changes made to the variable will persist across calls.

**EDIT**: As the comment says, this isn't the right way. Daniel Fischer's solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the maximum value of `i` as a second parameter to limit the number of lines to print i.e. the maximum value for `i`.

Comment: I'm sorry for not specifying: I can only use one parameter. I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: @StevenH that would be another option. But if you can just use a single parameter, Daniel Fischer has the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a two parameters function:

```
public void printTriangle(int i, int n) {
    if(i <= n) {
         System.out.println(printStars(i));
         printTriangle(i+1, n);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified: I can only use one parameter.